# Using .offset().top to find Elements position on page

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV I want to scroll with the page but it's not visible above the fold so I'm using this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get scrolling position of document   
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();

    // if its more than the top of the element
    if (scrollYpos > 551 ) {

         // Add a margin to the top 
         $('#scrollingDiv').animate({'margin-top': scrollYpos - 541 }, {duration: 300, queue: false});
    } else {
         $('#scrollingDiv').animate({'margin-top': 0 }, {duration: 200, queue: false});
    }}); // end scroll
```

ATM I'm giving it the vertical position of the DIV manually (551px). I want to do it dynamically.

```
var elYpos = $('#scrollingDiv').offset().top
```

So this finds the vertical position of the element on the page but when the element moves this changes which screws the rest up.

How can i get the position of the element once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defined your variable before the function so it's taken only once.

```
$(function(){
  var elYpos = $('#scrollingDiv').offset().top; // elYpos variable will stay as it's defined
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollYpos > elYpos ) {
    // and rest of tour code...
  });
});
```